# Lua shift element left and right in 2d array

Tags: arrays, lua, shift, lua-table

I have a 2d array : `grid[x][y]`

```
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28
31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38
41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48
```

Example:
I would like to move the 3rd column down, the bottom element goes into the first row like this:

```
41    2     3     4     5     6     7     8
 1    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
11    22    23    24    25    26    27    28
21    32    33    34    35    36    37    38
31    42    43    44    45    46    47    48
```

I used the following function to move the whole array left and right but in 2d array this obviously doesn't work, because you have to move the element to another array if shifting it:

```
function wrap( t, l )
    -- change i=0 to move left and i=1 to right
    for i = 1, l do
        table.insert( t, 1, table.remove( t, #t ) )
    end
end
```

I tried this function in Lua scratchpad and it doesn't work...I can't figure out the logic without losing the element.

```
function shift( t, direction )

for i=1,#t do
    if(direction == "left") then
            if(i == 1) then
                tempElement = t[#t][6] 
            else
                tempElement = t[i-1][6]
            end
    else
            if(i == 7) then
                tempElement = t[1][6] 
            else
                tempElement = t[i+1][6]
            end
    end    

table.insert( t[i], 6, tempElement )
table.remove( t[i], 12)

end

end
```

How can I shift the elements to another column but same index, so `grid[5][1]` goes in `grid[4][1]` and so on.

Comment: Please rewrite this to clearly state what is you table structure, what operation you want to perform on it, and what you have tried.

Comment: Can you verify that the example goal is what you are looking for, I wasn't sure. Also you need to indicate whether `grid[x]` represents a row or a column of your example.

Comment: @Schollii http://codepad.org/Vrr5jGH6 i want to move the element thrue columns and rows...

Comment: Sorry Michael I took a look but this does not answer my two questions: 1. could you check that the second table in your post represents your table after the shift; if not, fix the post; 2. is `grid[1]` equal to `{1,      2, 3, ...  8}` (row-major) or `{1, 11, 21, 31, 41}` (column major)?

Comment: @Schollii grid[1] is {1,2,3,...8}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, you are trying to shift items *within* a column, example:

```
{{11,12,13},
 {21,22,23},
 {31,32,33}}
```

to

```
{{31,12,13},
 {11,22,23},
 {21,32,33}}
```

The following code uses your wrap function:

```
g={{11,12,13},{21,22,23},{31,32,33}}

function shifItemWithinRow( array, shift )
    shift = shift or 1 -- make second arg optional, defaults to 1
    for i = 1, shift do
        table.insert( array, 1, table.remove( array, #array ) )
    end
end

function shifItemWithinColumn( grid, columnID, shiftCount )
    shiftCount = shiftCount or 1 -- make second arg optional, defaults to 1

    -- copy all items from g into new table, shifted:
    local numRows = #grid
    local newCol = {}
    for i=1,numRows do -- 
         local newI = i+shiftCount
         if newI > numRows then newI = newI - numRows end
         if newI < 1       then newI = numRows - newI end
         newCol[newI] = grid[i][columnID]
    end

    -- copy all items into grid
    for i=1,numRows do -- # each row
         grid[i][columnID] = newCol[i]
    end
end

function printGrid(g)
    for i, t in ipairs(g) do 
        print('{' .. table.concat(t, ',') .. '}')
    end
end

printGrid(g)
shifItemWithinColumn(g, 1) -- shift col 1 by +1
print()
printGrid(g)
print()
shifItemWithinColumn(g, 1, -1)  -- shift col 1 by -1
printGrid(g)
```

This example shifts a column by +1 then by -1 (so final is same as start).

Comment: it moves the whole table instead of the element ?

Comment: Does the solution shown move whole table? No, because it only shifts items from third row (`wrap(g[3])`). Do you want it to shift whole table?

Comment: look at this link please: http://codepad.org/lWv0BtrN in [1][1].key = 4, [2][1].key = 4,[3][1].key = 2. i then shift it with your code to left... it should do this [1][1].key = 4, [2][1].key = 2,[3][1].key = 4. the rest stays the same...just those indexes change

Comment: @MichaelAngelo Ah so you want to shift a column's items! But this is not what the output in your post shows (look at second table). That's why I was asking you to check it and correct if necessary. Please edit your post! I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Scholliii this is perfect! this is what i wanted all the time! can i also use it to move it like this (updated question)

Comment: @MichaelAngelo Please do not change the question like that. now people can't understand what this answer is about. Please revert your edit, accept this answer, and try it out yourself, if it doesn't work, try to make it work, and only then, post another question with what you tried.

Comment: i edited it back to make it somewhat clearer. i tried it but it ends up adding a index i will try further i thought maybe you know it. tnx for your help!

Comment: @MichaelAngelo Doesn't look like your revert worked. You have to use "rollback", I did it for you.